# In what maven2 repository can Google Guice be found?

Tags: maven-2, repository, guice

As far as I understand [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) 2.0 is out not so long ago. But I see that central repo still has outdated [1.0](http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.guice/guice) version. Please, tell where can I find maven2 repository with Google Guice 2.0.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Guice 3.0 is now [available on central](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/).  You'll need the following to depend on it.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Sadly, they [haven't uploaded source jars](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=382), and the class files have been [compiled with Java 6](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=402).  This may be a show-stopper for you…

Comment: Note that guice 3.0 is also available on central now.

Comment: It seems they have added the sources

Comment: Sources currently are present in the repository and class files are compiled with Java 5.

Answer (score 4):

Guice 2.0 is now available in the official google-maven-repository.  To use it, add the following to your pom.xml inside of the `<dependencies>` tag (you'll need to add one if there isn't one):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You shouldn't need to, but you can add a reference to the official google-maven-repository in your pom.xml by following the instructions [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-maven-repository/wiki/ProjectSetup).

Comment: Good point, it should probably be the default "compile" scope http://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't see Guice 2.0 in central I thought I'd include a stable repo where I found it:

- https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-uploads/

The [Grails OpenID plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-openid) references http://guice-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ but that doesn't have it (currently).

Answer (score 2):

They will put it to the central repository soon, as they promised here: http://groups.google.com/group/google-guice/browse_thread/thread/6707a887ed5ef2e3

Comment: Yup. Sorry about the delay! Hopefully we'll have something ready tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. [Guice-maven](http://code.google.com/p/guice-maven/) is intended to provide this.

Comment: -1: Guice *is* getting released to Central. Please standardize on that (as the answer above states it will be deployed very soon)

Answer (score 0):

Until it reaches the central repository, I've been getting it from here: http://guice-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk

Comment: http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/dependencies/maven2   this one contains more artifacts